How to compare two file systems... diff doesn't work?
I have a linux system on a micro-SD card which is acting strangely. I want to see which files have changed since I imaged the card from an image file. So, I mount the image file linux partition as /mnt and the SD card linux partition as /mnt2. Now, I try a diff, and I get nonsense like this:
    rw@seven:/> sudo diff -qr /mnt/ /mnt2/
    diff: /mnt/bin/nc: No such file or directory
    diff: /mnt2/bin/nc: No such file or directory
    diff: /mnt/bin/netcat: No such file or directory
    diff: /mnt2/bin/netcat: No such file or directory
    diff: /mnt/bin/systemd: No such file or directory
    diff: /mnt2/bin/systemd: No such file or directory
    (etc)

This command is recommended by a number of searches, such as
https://www.tecmint.com/compare-find-difference-between-two-directories-in-linux/
I've tried variations on this theme, but haven't found one that works.
How can I compare these two file systems to see what has changed?
    rw@seven:/> diff --version
    diff (GNU diffutils) 3.6
    Packaged by openSUSE


What are the filesystems? Are they FUSE? What are the exact commands you run to mount them? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

The messages sound like your diff is trying to follow symlinks. Do a ls -l /mnt/bin/nc or even namei -l /mnt/bin/nc and see where it points – it might point to an absolute "/usr/bin" path which leads to your host OS, rather than relative "usr/bin". Use --no-dereference to disable this.
I would suggest trying some tools from the Reproducible Builds project, as finding differences between two build outputs is a major part of eliminating them – specifically diffoscope, which compares both the data and metadata of two directory trees.
